# Unable to fill a custom choicefield form on Django

Tags: python, django, forms, choicefield

I'm new on DJango and I'm trying to fill a choicefield form with custom data but I'm getting an error that I don't understand well.

On my `views.py` I have:

```
def simpleDeploy(request):
    networkList = getDetailsNetworkPartitions(request)
    policiesList = getDetailsApplicationPolicies(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        abs(5) #Don't do nothing by the moment, I need put something or I get an error
    else:
        simpleForm = SimpleDeploy(netList=networkList, polList=policiesList)
    return render(request, 'apacheStratos/simpleDeploy.html', {'form': simpleForm})
```

And my `forms.py` is:

```
class SimpleDeploy(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, networkList, policiesList, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SimpleDeploy, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if networkList and policiesList:
            self.fields['networkPartitions'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=networkList)
            self.fields['applicationPolicies'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=policiesList)
        else:
            self.fields['networkPartitions'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices='No network partitions found')
            self.fields['applicationPolicies'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices='No application policies found')
```

The error that Django throws it's: `__init__() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)` on the line `simpleForm = SimpleDeploy(netList=networkList, polList=policiesList)`

I don't know why says that takes 3 arguments and gives 1 if I'm passing 2.

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

EDITED TO PUT ERROR AND TRACEBACK:

Error:

```
TypeError at /stratos/simpleDeploy

__init__() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/stratos/simpleDeploy
Django Version:     1.8.12
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

__init__() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)

Exception Location:     /home/iago/Escritorio/tfm/website/apacheStratos/views.py in simpleDeploy, line 60
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python2.7
Python Version:     2.7.6
Python Path:    

['/home/iago/Escritorio/tfm/website',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.12-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/iago/Escritorio/tfm/website',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']

Server time:    Thu, 14 Jul 2016 11:39:42 +0000
```

Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/stratos/simpleDeploy

Django Version: 1.8.12
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'contact',
 'menu',
 'catalog',
 'apacheStratos')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.12-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/iago/Escritorio/tfm/website/apacheStratos/views.py" in simpleDeploy
  60.         simpleForm = SimpleDeploy(netList=networkList, polList=policiesList)

Exception Type: TypeError at /stratos/simpleDeploy
Exception Value: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I've updated my question with the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have used a different key, and the positional arguments are missing. The arguments you are sending are being considered as `kwargs`.

In the form's `__init__` you are expecting the following arguments

```
def __init__(self, networkList, policiesList, *args, **kwargs):
```

But you are sending it with the keys `netList`, and `polList` Hence the error.

Try:

```
simpleForm = SimpleDeploy(networkList=netList, policiesList=polList)
```

Or even just

```
simpleForm = SimpleDeploy(netList, polList)
```

Note that i do not know what your local variables names are, so update them accordingly.

Comment: Oh, seems to work!!! Thanks. But I get an: too many values to unpack error on { form.as_table }} during template rendering. Why? If it's a choicefiled it should accept a list of strings with the choices. Or I'm wrong.

Comment: I guess the issue is, it expects a list of tuples.. You might want to look into the choice field format django forms expect it to be in

Comment: Ah, ok. I will see. Thanks!